# How can I remove the chapter name "Table of Contents" inside the table of contents?

Tags: table-of-contents

Is there a way how to remove the Chapter of table of contents in the table of contents itself? Since it is not a chapter of the document yet.The ToC name is made with this line: `\renewcommand\contentsname{Inhaltsverzeichnis}`
Thanks a lot in advance.

```
\documentclass[ngerman,12pt,a4paper,oneside,listof=totoc,plainfootsepline]{scrbook}
\addtokomafont{disposition}{\rmfamily} 
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[beforeskip=-.5\baselineskip,afterskip=.25\baselineskip]{subsubsection}

\input{Kapitel/Voreinstellungen}

\begin{document}
    
\input{Kapitel/Deckblatt}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\addtocontents{toc}{~\hfill\textbf{Page}\par}
\input{Kapitel/C1}
\input{Kapitel/C2}
\input{Kapitel/C3}
\input{Kapitel/C4}

\renewcommand\contentsname{Inhaltsverzeichnis}

\tableofcontents
%\pagestyle{plain}

\listoffigures
\listoftables
\vspace{1cm}
\begingroup
\let\clearpage\relax
%\listofformels
\vspace{1cm}
%\input{Kapitel/FZV}
\input{Kapitel/AF}
\endgroup
\newpage
    
    
\pagenumbering{arabic}
\setcounter{page}{1}
\input{Kapitel/Hauptkapitel/1_E}
\input{Kapitel/Hauptkapitel/2_G}
%\input{Kapitel/Hauptkapitel/3_SDT}
\input{Kapitel/Hauptkapitel/4_Kz}
\input{Kapitel/Hauptkapitel/RP}
%\input{Kapitel/Hauptkapitel/V}
\input{Kapitel/Hauptkapitel/ZF}
\input{Kapitel/Hauptkapitel/A}

\newpage    
\pagenumbering{Roman}
\setcounter{page}{12}
%\interlinepenalty 10000                    
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\begin{thebibliography}{10}
....
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Please remember to use self contained examples. We do not have all those chapters you input and thus cannot test your example.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem.

Comment: We also do not have the `Kapitel/Voreinstellungen` file.  By default there is no entry for the ToC in the ToC list. Off topic: If the language of your document is german, you can load package `babel` with option `ngerman`. Then you can remove the redefinition of `\contentsname`.

Answer (score 1):

Too long for a comment.

I have tried your MWE which failed because of all the "input" files you did not provide. I then painfully edited your MWE to comment out all `\input` macros but also added a single `\chapter{A chapter}` command. The result is shown below.

[image]

This is the table of contents page which does not include the ToC title in the ToC. As you state that you get the ToC title in the ToC then the problem must be in one or more of the many files you have not provided. How do you expect any help? --- GOM